# cloud service and db between two subscriptions in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, service, cloud

I have two subscription in an azure account

After I only changed sql database from subscription A to subscription B,

The website slowed down.

Now sql database is in subscription A.
And cloud service is in subscription B.

Could this be related?

Comment: Depends, did the resources end up in different regions maybe?

Comment: Location is same

Answer (score 0):

> Now SQL database is in subscription A, and cloud service is in subscription B.
>
> Could this be related?

The short answer: no.

The slightly longer answer: there might be multiple factors that impact the performance between the Cloud Service and the database. You could think of location, network, hardware, SKU/tier and so on. The subscription the database is in should *not* be one of them.

As long as all other properties of the database and the server it runs on are the same as they were previously, there should be little to no difference in the performance of the connection between the two.

> Azure continuously monitors the latency (speed) of core areas of its network using internal monitoring tools as well as measurements collected by ThousandEyes, a third-party synthetic monitoring service.

and

> Monthly latency numbers across Azure regions do not change regularly.

Also, this might be an interesting read: [Microsoft global network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/microsoft-global-network).